# Old Xbox game update

Tags: xbox-360, call-of-duty-black-ops-3

I recently got an Xbox from 2009/10 and I bought black ops III for it. However, I can not seem to play the game. The first time I put the disk in it prompted me that an update was necessary and I selected update (My Xbox is not connected to the internet nor do I have an Xbox Live account) after the update "finished" (it took less then a minute) the Xbox sent me back to home where I selected to run the game. After doing so the screen goes black and after ten seconds or so it takes me back to home.

If you have any solutions on how to make the game run please share.

Comment: have you tried connecting to the internet.

Comment: In the event that they can't connect the console to the internet at all for some reason, it should still work. Just talked to an Activision representative, and they said that the game should work even if there is no internet connection or Xbox Live account active during the installation and initial launch of the game. There's got to be something else going on here.

Comment: @pushasha no i have yet to try connecting to the internet. I am in the process of doing that now

Comment: have you checked if the previous owner perhaps played bo3 on that console? if so, check if there are any updates (for BO3) installed on the hard drive and remove those. One of the updates might be partially corrupt

Comment: Black ops 3? Xbox from 2010? That doesnt.... sound right at all. Xbox 360 right? I thought blops 3 was ps4/xbone/pc, not last gen consoles....

Comment: @AlexSpencer There was an Xbox 360 version of Black Ops 3, but it cut out a LOT of stuff from the current gen versions, including the single-player campaign.

Comment: @sequoiad ahh okay. that makes more sense then. wait what about advanced warfare then? @.@

Answer (score 1):

first I would address the major question of do you have a hard drive in the system.

An update typically will require some sort of storage either internal or external with a USB drive. second it is possible to install updates using a USB drive by downloading the update from the Microsoft/Xbox site.

Some games may have the necessary update parts on the disk itself but requires space to install it. some systems will try to install updates but cannot get past a certain point due to not having storage.

Finally, you may want to look into the console version as if you are running an older version there are many people that will pay good money for your system if it is not updated as updates have disabled many mods and jtags and finding suitable consoles is getting harder. So you may consider selling that box and get more than enough for another.

Answer (score 1):

The Xbox 360 version of Black Ops III doesn't contain local play. It is only the online multiplayer component of the game. Connect to the internet and the game should start.

Answer (score 0):

This happens to me as well but after troubleshooting for a while I got the game working. You need to make sure the disk is clean and not scratched, but also make sure you have Xbox LIVE, you get access to Xbox LIVE when you put your email on your offline account and have an internet connection